# arranging 3 subfloats, two small ones next to a big one

Tags: positioning, subfloats

I am trying to place 3 sufloats on a figure, and I have found [this post](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=23420) on the internet that is using the `\subfigure` command. In my document, however, I'm using the `subfig` package as I understand it is a better option. Yet I am unable to replicate the following figure, as shown in that site:

[image]

The proposed code given on that site to make this work is:

```
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
          \rule{\linewidth}{\dimexpr 2\linewidth+2\baselineskip+6pt}
      \caption{First}\label{subfig-1:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
            \rule{\linewidth}{\linewidth}
        \caption{Second}\label{subfig-2:dummy}
      \end{subfigure}\\[\baselineskip]
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
            \rule{\linewidth}{\linewidth}
        \caption{Third}\label{subfig-3:dummy}
      \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Dummy figure}\label{fig:dummy}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

but I'm unable to change this to use subflots.

Comment: The proposed code is *not* using the `\subfigure` *command* (from the obsolete `subfigure` package), but the `subfigure` *environment* from the `subcaption` package.

Comment: Indeed, I just realized that. Thanks @GonzaloMedina.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proposed code is *not* using the `\subfigure` *command* (from the obsolete `subfigure` package) which shouldn't be used anymore, but the `subfigure` *environment* from the `subcaption` package and, depending on your actual document class, it could be possible to use that code with no problems.

If you, however, want to use the `subfig` package, here's one option using `tabular` and the `adjustbox` package to easily produce and change the desired alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \adjustbox{valign=b}{\subfloat[First\label{subfig-1:dummy}]{%
          \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth,height=8.1cm]{example-image-a}}}
    &      
    \adjustbox{valign=b}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \subfloat[Second\label{subfig-2:dummy}]{%
          \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}} \\
    \subfloat[Third\label{subfig-3:dummy}]{%
          \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
    \end{tabular}}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Dummy figure}\label{fig:dummy}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]